# Выделять блок, если "доскроллил" до него

Tags: jquery

Есть к примеру в тексте заголовки `<h1>` и есть справа блок, в котором создаются ссылки с названием этих заголовков.

При скролле, когда позиция скролла ниже заголовка, в блоке справа должна выделяться ссылка текущего заголовка.

А при нажатие на ссылку страница должна пролистовываться до выбранного заголовка.

Прямо как в Стиме, в "руководствах".

Я попытался такое написать, но моих познаний хватило только на создание ссылок в блоке справа.

Как реализовать скролл при нажатии на ссылку до заголовка - я знаю.
А вот как реализовать "выделение" ссыки когда доскроллил до заголовка - я не знаю.

Пример в [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CbIPoK2513/xqxrppsb/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно чуть чуть допилить )) А так в общем работает ))

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var hMess = $('.message h1');
  if(hMess.length >= 1) {
  hMess.each(function(){
    var hMessName = $(this).text();
   $('.mess-menu').append('<a href="#'+hMessName+'">'+hMessName+'</a>');
  });
  }
  $('.mess-menu').append('<div class="eventScroll"></div><div class="eventH1"></div>');
  addEvents();
});

function addEvents() {
  $('.mess-menu a').click(function() {
    $('body, html').stop();
    console.log($(this).text());
    let destination = $('#' + $(this).text() ).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate(
      {scrollTop: destination}, 0, 'linear'
    );
  });
  window.addEventListener('scroll', changeMenu);
}

function changeMenu() {
  let scrollBoxsHtml = $('.message h1');
  let activeNummer = scrollBoxsHtml.length - 1;
  
  for (let i = scrollBoxsHtml.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (scrollBoxsHtml[i].getBoundingClientRect().top >= 0) {
      activeNummer = i;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  $('.mess-menu a').removeClass('active')
  $('.mess-menu a').eq(activeNummer).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
.message {display: block; width: calc(100% - 160px); margin-right: 10px;}
.mess-menu {display: block; width: 150px; position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0;}
.mess-menu a {display: block; width: calc(100% - 20px); padding: 3px 10px; color: #000 !important; text-decoration: none;}
.mess-menu a.active, .mess-menu a:hover {background: #ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message">
<h1 id="Один">Один</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur tempus pretium quam, in bibendum tellus rhoncus feugiat. Nulla porta tellus nec orci tempor, non facilisis augue commodo. Proin vel ex odio. In in efficitur turpis.
<br><br>
In imperdiet eleifend efficitur. Proin posuere pulvinar venenatis. Quisque accumsan luctus velit. Sed ante orci, efficitur sit amet orci porta, consectetur egestas massa.
<br><br>
Sed tincidunt gravida erat vel sodales. Ut fermentum, sem quis mattis vehicula, nulla massa varius purus, sit amet fermentum tortor purus sed felis. Vestibulum laoreet tristique est, nec lobortis lectus ornare in. Proin a ipsum pharetra, euismod ipsum sagittis, cursus lacus. Maecenas ultrices ligula sit amet justo porta iaculis. Praesent nunc massa, finibus eu nunc a, gravida molestie lacus. Sed at mauris erat. Praesent at condimentum eros, faucibus aliquet tortor. Suspendisse porta risus at eros efficitur, a finibus eros scelerisque. Cras id ante rutrum massa malesuada viverra. Praesent sed est nec magna iaculis porta. Curabitur elementum tincidunt purus, sed porttitor justo ornare mattis. Donec gravida sagittis quam eget facilisis. Ut rhoncus placerat odio mollis condimentum. Aliquam viverra erat rutrum dolor tincidunt semper. 

<h1 id="two">two</h1>
Nam sed faucibus tortor. Morbi lacinia neque eget orci posuere, id vehicula lacus ornare. Fusce blandit, est nec convallis interdum, ex nisl tristique erat, eu venenatis ex purus eu odio. Cras elementum nunc lectus, quis porttitor nisl ultrices a. Pellentesque ac odio eget eros blandit aliquet. Sed nisi enim, tristique volutpat elit et, vehicula rutrum risus. Curabitur a hendrerit orci, a gravida massa. Ut aliquet odio in vulputate pellentesque. 
<br><br>
In eu enim eu purus dignissim tincidunt quis sit amet orci. Suspendisse sem nunc, finibus at pharetra ut, tempor vel massa. Aliquam et lorem molestie, vestibulum ligula vitae, tempor leo. Pellentesque vitae consectetur quam. Nulla ultrices est quis lorem tincidunt tincidunt. Sed aliquet ac elit nec accumsan. Nullam mollis ut turpis at condimentum. Duis pretium purus quis turpis finibus imperdiet. Nulla nec lacus quis leo consequat sollicitudin sit amet ac erat. Donec facilisis neque id mauris eleifend, non eleifend enim auctor. Sed interdum varius risus, fermentum rhoncus metus rutrum nec. Nulla tempor ultrices ex, eu elementum nisl placerat sed. Quisque vestibulum maximus arcu, quis consequat mauris sollicitudin non. Proin molestie nulla et semper volutpat. 

<h1 id="three">three</h1>
Praesent in orci et eros congue molestie. Duis sit amet eros nec metus elementum pellentesque ut id tortor. Sed sollicitudin sollicitudin diam vel pellentesque. Donec consectetur tempus tristique. Aliquam ultricies auctor metus, ut dictum justo rutrum vel. Nulla aliquet augue nec eros ultricies hendrerit. Mauris elit nisl, rhoncus eget convallis nec, cursus sit amet magna. Duis in faucibus leo, in dignissim massa. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse in tempor nibh, auctor ullamcorper lacus. Praesent efficitur hendrerit pharetra. Sed orci magna, viverra molestie erat tempus, pulvinar lobortis lacus. Sed ligula neque, accumsan at malesuada at, lobortis in dui. Suspendisse lectus ante, mollis sed lobortis at, rhoncus a tortor.
</div>

<div class="mess-menu">
  
</div>
```

Comment: рад помочь )))))))))))))))

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке страницы учитывался не верх экрана, а середина?