# Как изменять стиль толко одного элемента в меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css, скрипт

Нужно чтобы из меню (4 элементов белого цвета и один черный) при нажатии на элемент, у него менялся цвет на черный, а если нажать еще раз на другой, то у этого цвет становится опять белым, а у того на который нажали черным. То есть черным может быть только один элемент из 5-ти. + при повторном нажатии на черный элемент он не должен менять цвет на белый. Не могу допереть, как это сделать.

И еще вопросик.. Как сделать так, чтобы при прокручивании страницы на определенные секции, эти же элементы менялись. То есть, допустим мы до листали до 3-ей секции и у нас черный 3-ий элемент. А когда до листали до 4-ой, 3 элемент становился белым, а четвертый черным.

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!!!

Comment: Вы хоть что-нибудь уже сделали?

Comment: Нужно? Сделай, ни кто не возражает...

Answer (score 2):

Правильно понял задание?

Если да, то разберём:
У нас есть меню, при нажатие на раздел мы ставим ему цвет.
Но перед этим мы у всех разделов "обнуляем" `style`.

```js
var itemClick = $('ul li');
itemClick.on('click',function(){
  itemClick.attr('style','');
  $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

```css
ul li {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

---

Ответ на второй вопрос вот по этой [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/834095/221218)

Comment: А зачем ради такой простой задачи тянуть целую библиотеку?

Comment: Как пример. Лично я JQ использую всегда, вот и написал на нём.

Comment: Пример неплохой, но тянуть jQ всегда тоже не стоит. ;) Плюс вам кинул.

Answer (score 1):

Берёте и вешайте на элемент `onClick = "f"`

```
function f () {
    // Делаете что вам нужно
}
```

Comment: Это понятно, но тогда можно все элементы выделить. А мне надо, чтобы выделялся только один из пяти.

Comment: На все пять элементов вешайте onClick()

Answer (score -2):

то что ты хочешь сделать называется табуляция (в гугле вводишь "css табуляция меню")
вот ссылка с примерами реализации
http://shpargalkablog.ru/2012/03/css-tabs.html